# Changing ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking 2 for simple URL request

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, afnetworking-2

I'm working on an update of an iOS app that another developer created.
They used ASIHTTPRequest, but I thought I should switch to AFNetworking so that the whole app can be ARC. I'm not experienced in writing networking applications, so I'm finding AFNetworking 2 very confusing. After including the files in my project and adding the header with #import "AFNetworking.h" is there an easy way to adjust the following method in RSSReader.m so that it works?

Here is the existing code:

```
-(NSArray*)readUTF16LEFeed:(NSURL*) urlToRead{
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:urlToRead];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
lastModified = [NSDate date];
NSData *response = [request responseData];//UTF-16LE
NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding: NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
DLog(@"string is: %@",responseString);
responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ISO-8859-1" withString:@"UTF16-LE"];
NSData* data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
return [self parseNamesFromXML:data];
}
return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add import

`#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager+AutoRetry.h"`

And try to use this code

```
-(void)readUTF16LEFeed:(NSString*) urlToRead{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    void (^successBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, id responseObject) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, id responseObject){
        //work with response
        //NSData *response = [request responseData];//UTF-16LE
        NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding: NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
        responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ISO-8859-1" withString:@"UTF16-LE"];
        NSData* data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];

    };
    void (^failureBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, NSError * error) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, NSError * error){
        //if error do this
    };
    [manager GET:urlToRead parameters:nil success:successBlock failure:failureBlock autoRetry:5 retryInterval:2];
}
```

Comment: I don't have the file "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager+AutoRetry.h"

Comment: I don't have the file "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager+AutoRetry.h" But if I use "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h" it builds with 3 warnings:  for -(void)readUTF16LEFeed:(NSString*) urlToRead{
 I get the warning "Conflicting return type in implementation of 'readUTF16LEFeed:': NSArray *' vs 'void' .  The second warning is "unused variable 'data'. And the third warning is "instance method not found" on the last line.

Comment: AutoRetry is useful category [github](https://github.com/shaioz/AFNetworking-AutoRetry).  NSArray *' vs 'void' - change in .h file -(NSArray*)readUTF16LEFeed:(NSURL*) urlToRead to -(void)readUTF16LEFeed:(NSString*) urlToRead

Comment: Perfect tutorial was [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial)

Comment: I added the folder to my project, but now it gets errors for "ObjcAssociatedObjectHelpers.h file not found" and <AFNetworking+AutoRetry/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager+AutoRetry.h> not found.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to just use something like [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler] to accomplish the same task without using any 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Yes, you can use simple sendAsynchronousRequest. But you ask about changing ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking 2. This is powerful library with caching, loading imageView and smth... For a single query isn't necessary

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize it was an option at first.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but since I still can't get it to work, I've re-asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422301/using-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletionhandler-for-url-request) regarding a solution using NSURLConnection.